# LabWindows/CVI - Image processing

Tags: c, cvi

I am trying to convert an image from RGB to black and white image (0 or 1). At first I have converted it to grayscale but now i'm stuck (the idea was to finde the middle which I did using matlabe and now I need to normalize evrything..).
Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Were you able to convert it to grayscale manually or are you using any kind of function? If you are doing it manually, you can just set a threshold for the gray level, so below that threshold all values will be 0 and upper that threshold all the values will be 255, or 1 if you are storing that into a matrix

Comment: Anyway I would suggest you to have a look to opencv or any other Image processing library (there are simplers) since CVI uses some sort of extended ANSI C